# Can anyone give me a list of the Business Objects Error Codes and what they mean?

Tags: business-objects

Business Objects Web Services returns error codes and I have yet to find a good resource where these are listed and what they mean.  I am currently getting an "The resultset was empty. (Error: WBP 42019)".  Any ideas on where these might be listed?  I've called Business Objects support and the tech couldn't even tell me.  Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I have found is the "Error Message Guide" from Business Objects.  http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir2/en/xir2_ErrMsgGde_en.pdf

If you can't find the error code in that guide then you end up having to deal with standard debugging of an undocumented application.
 1. Read the message, maybe that will help.
 2. Check the logs on the server, local machine if DeskI.
 3. See if the [BOB Forum](http://forumtopics.com/busobj/index.php) has the answer in its search.

The example you have listed appears to be that no data was retrieved.  Double check that the query that was generated is correct and should normally bring back results.

Comment: It looks like that guide doesn't have that error message.  I did determine that the another process was removing the document before I retrieved it from the server.  I have solved this particular problem but am stuck as to know where to look for other errors I have seen.  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best place that I have found:

http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/errors/12/0/en/html/idxentries.htm

Each error code is a link with a description.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [This](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/communitycs/TechnicalPapers/pecodes.pdf?recDnlReq=Record&dnlPath=pecodes.pdf)? (PDF Link - beware)

Found here: (Google cache, as the page appears dead):
http://209.85.173.104/search?q=cache:fyB21Ywrj-MJ:support.businessobjects.com/communityCS/TechnicalPapers/pecodes.pdf.asp+%22Business+Objects%22+%22Error+Codes%22&hl=en&ct=clnk&cd=1&gl=us

Answer (score 0):

**Error list for SAP DI API(SDK) - SAP B1 9.3**

This list could be found inside the SDK installation directory:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SAP Business One SDK\Samples\UDO\Include\VS6\__SBOERR.h

Here is its content, which pretty well explains all errors:

```
#ifndef __SBOERR_H_
#define __SBOERR_H_

typedef long SBOErr;

#define dbdError                    -1
#define noErr                       0
#define errNoMsg                    -10
#define coreEndOfFile               -39
#define coreFileNotFound            -43
#define coreFileBusy                -47
#define coreFileNotOpened           -50
#define coreFileCorrupted           -51
#define coreDivisionByZero          -99
#define coreOutOfMemory             -100
#define corePrinterError            -101
#define corePrintCanceled           -103
#define coreMoneyOverflow           -104
#define coreInvalidPointer          -111
#define coreError                   -199
#define coreBadDirectory            -213
#define coreFileExists              -214
#define coreInvalidFilePermission   -216
#define coreInvalidPath             -217
#define coreBadPassword             -218
#define coreBadUser                 -219
#define coreUpgradePerformed        -221
#define coreNoCurrPeriodErr         -222
#define coreLanguageInitErr         -8020

/* DBM Errors */
#define dbmFirstError           -1000
#define dbmBadColumnType        -1001
#define dbmNotSupported         -1002
#define dbmAliasNotFound        -1003
#define dbmValueNotFound        -1004
#define dbmBadDate              -1005
#define dbmNoDefaultColumn      -1012
#define dbmZeroOrBlankValue     -1013
#define dbmIntegerTooLarge      -1015
#define dbmBadValue             -1016
#define dbmOtherFileNotRelated  -1022
#define dbmOtherKeyNotInMainKey -1023
#define dbmArrayRecordNotFound  -1025
#define dbmMustBePositive       -1027
#define dbmMustBeNegative       -1028
#define dbmColumnNotUpdatable   -1029
#define dbmBadNumValue          -1030
#define dbmBadTimeValue         -1031
#define dbmBadMoneyValue        -1032
#define dbmNotUserDataSource    -1033

#define dbmCannotAllocEnv       -1100
#define dbmBadConnection        -1101
#define dbmConnectionNotOpen    -1102
#define dbmDatabaseExists       -1103
#define dbmCannotCreateDatabase -1104

#define dbmInternalError        -1200

#define dbmBadParameters        -2001
#define dbmTooManyTables        -2003
#define dbmTableNotFound        -2004
#define dbmBadDefinition        -2006
#define dbmBadDAG               -2007
#define dbmBadRecordOffset      -2010
#define dbmNoColumns            -2013
#define dbmBadColumnIndex       -2014
#define dbmBadIndexNumber       -2015
#define dbmBadAlias             -2017
#define dbmAliasAlreadyExists   -2018
#define dbmBadColumnSize        -2020
#define dbmBadColumLevel        -2022
#define dbmDAGsNoMatch          -2024
#define dbmNoKeys               -2025
#define dbmPartialDataFound     -2027
#define dbmNoDataFound          -2028
#define dbmColumnsNoMatch       -2029
#define dbmDuplicateKey         -2035
#define dbmRecordLocked         -2038
#define dbmDataWasChanged       -2039
#define dbmEndOfSort            -2045
#define dbmNotOpenForWrite      -2049
#define dbmNoMatchWithDAG       -2056
#define dbmBadContainerOffset   -2062
#define dbmLoadExtLibFailed     -2100
#define dbmRowSizeTooLong       -2110 // the size of the table row is over the Sql limit 8K
#define dbmLastError            -2999

//db2 specific errors
#define dbmdb2AttachFailed      -2101
#define dbmdb2CreateDBFailed    -2102
#define dbmdb2DeAttachFailed    -2103
#define dbmdb2BackupFailed      -2104

//sybase specific errors
#define dbmSybaseDeviceCreationFailed    -2200

// QRY errors
#define qryNotDefined           -1
#define qryFirstError           -3000
#define qryColumnNotFound       -3001
#define qryBadVarNum            -3003
#define qryWrongToken           -3004
#define qryTokenAfterEnd        -3005
#define qryUnexpectedEnd        -3006
#define qryQueryTooLong         -3008
#define qryExtraRightPar        -3009
#define qryNoRightPar           -3010
#define qryNoOpcode             -3012
#define qryNoColInComp          -3013
#define qryBadCondition         -3014
#define qryBadSortList          -3015
#define qryNoString             -3017
#define qryTooManyColumns       -3018
#define qryTooManyIndices       -3019
#define qryTooManyTables        -3020
#define qryRefNotFound          -3021
#define qryBadRangeSet          -3022
#define qryBadParse             -3023
#define qryTwoArraysInQuery     -3024
#define qryVarMissing           -3025
#define qryBadInput             -3026
#define qryProgressAborted      -3027
#define qryBadTableIndex        -3028
#define qryBadQuery             -3032
#define qryEmptyRecord          -3033
#define qryNoImpYet             -3034
#define qryBadParameter         -3036
#define qryMissingTableInList   -3037
#define qryBadOperation         -3040
#define qryBadExpression        -3041
#define qryNameAlreadyExists    -3042
#define qryTimeExpired          -3044
#define qryBadCallbackNum       -3045
#define qryNoCallback           -3046
#define qryLastError            -3046

//FORM errors
#define formNoWindow                3001
#define formBadVarNum               3002
#define formTooManyVars             3003
#define formDuplicateUID            3004
#define formInvalidItem             3006
#define formTooManyForms            3007
#define formTooManySavedPtrs        3009
#define formInvalidForm             3012
#define formCantGetMultilineEdit    3015
#define formBadItemType             3016
#define formBadParameters           3017
#define formNoMessageProc           3023
#define formItemNotSelectable       3029
#define formBadValue                3031
#define formItemNotFound            3033
#define formAXCreateFailed          3034
#define formNotUserItem             3035
#define formItemNotEditable         3036
#define formItemFocusFailedNotVisible       3037
#define formItemFocusFailedNotEditable      3038
#define fromCloseAllFormsFailed             3039

// GRID errors
#define gridInvalidGrid             4007
#define gridBadSize                 4008
#define gridNoData                  4009
#define gridInvalidParams           4011
#define gridNoSuperTitle            4013
#define gridSuperTitle2Exits        4014
#define gridBadItemNum              4015
#define gridBadData                 4016
#define gridAlreadyFolded           4017
#define gridAlreadyExpanded         4018
#define gridLineExists              4019
#define gridNotEnoughData           4020
#define gridSuperTitlesExists       4022
#define gridRowNotCollapssible      4027
#define gridRowHasNoCollapseLevel   4028
#define gridInvalidRow              4029
#define gridItemSelectNotSupported  4030
#define gridInvalidColNum           4031
#define gridFocusFailedNotEditable          4032
#define gridFocusFailedNotVisible           4033
#define gridColumnFocusFailedNotEditable    4034

// SBAR
#define sbarNoSuchInfo          8004
#define sbarInfoOcccupied       8005
#define sbarProgressStopped     8007
#define sbarTooManyProgresses   8008
#define sbarNoMessageBar        8006

// GRAPH
#define graphInvalidGraph       5001
#define graphBadItemNum         5002
#define graphBadParameters      5005

// IBAR
#define ibarError               9000

// SCRIPT
#define     scFirstError            -9000
#define     scInvalidType           -9000
#define     scLineTooLarge          -9002
#define     scInvalidTokType        -9003
#define     scInvalidLine           -9004
#define     scInvalidFormType       -9005
#define     scInvalidOperator       -9006
#define     scInvalidScriptCall     -9007
#define     scItemNotValid          -9008
#define     scNotGird               -9009
#define     scUndefinedVar          -9010
#define     scRedefinedVar          -9011
#define     scNotVarOperation       -9012
#define     scIncompatVarType       -9013
#define     scStringTooLong         -9014
#define     scDivByZero             -9015
#define     scFileNotChoosen        -9016
#define     scFileNotOpen           -9017
#define     scSomeDataRead          -9018
#define     scIfNotClosed           -9020
#define     scLoopNotClosed         -9021
#define     scNotCompareThisType    -9022
#define     scLastError             -9022

// Reports
#define rptFirstError               -6100
#define rptNotValid                 -6100
#define rptDuplicateItem            -6101
#define rptBadParameters            -6200
#define rptColNotFound              -6250
#define rptBadVarNum                -6300
#define rptVarNotSet                -6305
#define rptBadStandardIndex         -6350
#define rptBadItemNum               -6370
#define rptBadItemType              -6373
#define rptItemFromAnotherPart      -6380
#define rptPassedPageLimit          -6390
#define rptProgressAborted          -6400
#define rptTooManyPages             -6450
#define rptNotPageFooter            -6500
#define rptNoQuery                  -6550
#define rptNotPicture               -6600
#define rptPrintCanceledByUser      -6650
#define rptMarginTooLarge           -6651
#define rptLoadExtLibFailed         -6652
#define rptLoadExtProcFailed        -6653
#define rptReportTooLongForExport   -6700
#define rptInvalidFieldIDFormat     -6710
#define rptFieldIDAlreadyExist      -6711
#define rptRecursiveDependency      -6712
#define rptFormulaGrammarError      -6713
#define rptSumItemCanOnlyBeInRepArea    -6714
#define rptNoSums                   -6715
#define rptDataTypeNoSuchMethod     -6716
#define rptFieldDoesnotExist        -6717
#define rptFieldNotEvaluatedYet     -6718
#define rptInvalidParameter         -6719
#define rptMethodNotSupported       -6720
#define rptTotalPageLiveAlone       -6721
#define rptRecursiveRelation        -6722
#define rptLastError                -6799

// Prog
#define progBadProgress                 9001
#define progProgressIsModal             9002
#define progProgressStopped             9003
#define progBadParams                   9004
#define progOnlyOneDim                  9005
#define progModalProgressAlreadyOn      9006


//Menus
#define menuNotOwnerDrawn               -11001
#define menuNotSupportedImageType       -11002
#define menuCannotLoadImageFile         -11003

//UI errors
#define uiDuplicateUniqueID             -7502
#define uiInvalidObject                 -7503
#define uiFunctionNotSupported          -7002
#define uiCannotSetFocusOnItem          -7653
#define uiSecuritySetFocusFailed        -7654
#define uiFailedLoadXml                 -7040
#define uiInvalidFieldValue             -7018

#define dataTableSourceDTEqualToTargetDT        -7751
#define dataTableDuplicateColumnUID             -7752 //4500
#define dataTableInvalidColumnIndex             -7753 //4501
#define dataTableInvalidColumnUid               -7754 //4502
#define dataTableInvalidDAG                     -7755 //4503
#define dataTableDuplicateUid                   -7756 //4504
#define dataTableInvalidUid                     -7757 //4505
#define dataTableInvalidIndex                   -7758 //4506
#define dataTableInvalidVaribleNumber           -7759 //4507
#define dataTableInvalidRowIndex                -7760 //4508
#define dataTableInvalidAlias                   -7761 //4509
#define dataTableLineExists                     -7762 //4510
#define dataTableInvalidItemType                -7763 //4511
#define dataTableNotWritable                    -7764 //4512
#define dataTableAlreadyConnectedToGrid         -7765 //4513
#define dataTableAlreadyConnectedToFormItem     -7766 //4514
#define dataTableColumnDataExceedsSize          -7767 //4515
#define dataTableInvalidValueType               -7768

#endif
```